# Integral of $\int \sin^5x\cdot \cos^3x \textrm{ d}x$, substituting $u=\cos x$ vs $u=\sin x$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I used the substitution $u=\cos x$ whereas my teacher used $u=\sin x$ and we get completely different answers of course, which do not seem to be equivalent. I don't understand how a single integral can have several solutions.

My answer: $-\frac{\cos^4x}{4}+\frac{2\cos^6x}{6}-\frac{\cos^8x}{8} + C$

My teacher's answer: $\frac{\sin^6x}{6}-\frac{\sin^8x}{8} + C$

Comment: Did you try differentiating both answers? What do you get?

Comment: What answers do you get, and do they both differentiate to $\sin^5x\cos^3x$?

Comment: Every indefinite integral has several different solutions. If $F=\int f$ then $F+C$ is also $\int f$, where $C$ is a constant function. In fact, if $F'=f$ then $(F+C)'=F'+C'=f+0=f$

Comment: In Wolfram Alpha I apparently get the same derivative, after what to me is a weird simplification. I guess that's part of why I was confused, the derivatives didn't look the same to me since I didn't simplify far enough.

Comment: Yes, and $\sin^2x+\cos^2x$ doesn't look like $1$ at first glance…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your solutions are missing the additive constant, so your solutions should be:

Your answer: $-\frac{\cos^4x}{4}+\frac{2\cos^6x}{6}-\frac{\cos^8x}{8} + C$

Your teachers answer: $\frac{\sin^6x}{6}-\frac{\sin^8x}{8} + C$

for each additional constant $C \in \Bbb R$

And you are both right :-)

Both of you found an antiderivative of $\sin^5(x)\cos^3(x)$ because of:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\frac{\cos^4x}{4}+\frac{2\cos^6x}{6}-\frac{\cos^8x}{8}\right) = \sin^5(x)\cos^3(x)$$

and

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\sin^6x}{6}-\frac{\sin^8x}{8}\right) = \sin^5(x)\cos^3(x)$$

Additionally you know now  that both of your solutions only differs by a constant $C \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Is it because of the constant that I don't get the same value when evaluating for e.g. $\frac{\pi}{3}$? It shouldn't be, right? Since there are no constants C in the expressions.

Comment: Yes… your functions differs by $\frac{1}{24}$… e.g. your solutions evaluated at $0$ is $\frac{-1}{24}$ your teacher's one is zero… hence $$-\frac{\cos^4x}{4}+\frac{2\cos^6x}{6}-\frac{\cos^8x}{8} + \frac{1}{24} = \frac{\sin^6x}{6}-\frac{\sin^8x}{8}$$
Checking it on $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ we get:

$$ \frac{1}{24} = \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{24}$$

Comment: I see. I thought $x$ represented an angle $\theta$. But it represents the value of $cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$? This way the expressions seem to be equal.

Comment: No… $x$ is a real number. OFC you can identify it with an angle. Your calculator should be set to RAD mode, not to DEG mode! (Or you have to plugin angles… e.g. $\frac{\pi}{2} = 90°$

Comment: Sorry I thought I had the same answer when evaluating at $\pi$ for $\cos x$ and $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ for $\sin x$, that is, when they both are equal to $-1$, but they were actually the negative of each other. Forget my last comment.

Comment: Don't know if this is too off-topic, but where does the constant $\frac{1}{24}$ come from?

Comment: To understand *why* they are equivalent, remember that $\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)$ and vice-versa.